# Bootstrap modal switch can't scroll the later modal

Tags: scroll, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which has a link to another modal. When I opened the second modal and close the first modal, I can't scroll the second modal, only the background content scrolls. Can any one help me to solve this? I am using bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Check if the new modal opens only when the first one is fully close, those events should not be overlapped

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SubjectDelta ,but how to make sure they don't overlapped.

Comment: Posting some of your code would make this much more easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Modal Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events) to be sure your modals will not overlap. In this case you must open the second modal after the first one, like this:

```
$('#first-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
    // Open your second one in here
});
```

If `.button` is the selector for those things that close the first modal to open the second one, you should have something like this

```
$('#first-modal').on('click', '.button', function() {
    // [...] Whatever you need to do after pushing one of those buttons
    $('#first-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
        // Open your second one in here
        $('#first-modal').off('hidden.bs.modal');
        // This will remove ANY event attached to 'hidden.bs.modal' label
    }).modal('hide');
});
```

If you want to use the first cleaner example, oyu should be able to test from the [`event` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) where it came from (if it's not one of your button, `event.preventDefault();` and quit)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have an item list on the first modal, what i want is when i click one of the items, it jumps to the detail modal of the item. Is there any way to check the state of the first modal? Or how can I transmit data to the hidden event from the item being clicked?

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot that I can put this event function inside the item click function.

Comment: Oh, noooo. That doesn't work well. The event function will be fired sometimes even the function he is in is not called.

Comment: $('#first-modal').on('click', '.button', function() {
    // [...] Whatever you need to do after pushing one of those buttons
    $('#first-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
        // Open your second one in here  The first time it's OK, but when I reopen the first modal and just dismiss it without clicking the modal2 firing button, this #first-modal hidden event fires. 
    }).modal('hide');
});

Comment: The first time it's OK, but when I reopen the first modal and just dismiss it without clicking the modal2 firing button, this #first-modal hidden event fires. IE 11 and firefox both work the same way

Comment: Add `$('#first-modal').off('hidden.bs.modal');`  where you open the second modal. I edited the answer